# Will passing lambdas to Observable.subscribe in kotlin result in memory leaks?

Tags: android, lambda, memory-leaks, kotlin, rx-java

See the following kotlin code:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        val disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                               .subscribe { textView.text = it.toString }
    }

}
```

Here I am am passing a lambda expression in the subscribe method instead of an anonymous inner classses. So is it required to call `disposable.dispose()` in order to prevent memory leaks? Or the lambda expression won't keep an implicit reference to the instance of the MainActivity class.

And if I do need to dispose it, what is the best way and why?

Answer (score 0):

I added a logger to the Observable.subscribe() as follows:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            val disposable = Observable.interval(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()).subscribe {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Interval:" + it.toString())
                                textView.text = it.toString 
                            }
        }

    }
```

and noticed that even after exiting the app by pressing the back key, the observable kept running. So I added the following code to onDestroy():

```
override fun onDestroy() {
    disposable.dispose()
    super.onDestroy()
}
```

and now everything is working as expected